# just list only files and not recursively in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I wonder whether there is some option in find or ls to print just files and not directories in the working directory.

```
find ./ -type f
```

prints all files recursively, but what i need is just files in this folder

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from `man find`

```
-maxdepth  
   Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of directories below the 
   command line arguments. `-maxdepth 0' means only apply the tests and actions to the    
   command line arguments.
```

`find . -type f -maxdepth 1`  should do what you want

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `maxdepth` option to limit the recursion.

```
find ./ -type f -maxdepth 1
```

Comment: thanks, but why I get the error find: 0652-017 --maxdepth is not a valid option.

Comment: sorry, typo, try  `-maxdepth` instead (one -)

Comment: please try this: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`

Comment: What version of Unix are  you ssh'ing to?

Comment: -depth Always evaluates to the value True. Causes the descent of the directory
hierarchy to be done so that all entries in a directory are affected before the
directory itself is affected. This can be useful when the find command is used
with the cpio command to transfer files that are contained in directories
without write permission.

Comment: is it the equivalent of maxdepth? in my man find the option depth exists

Comment: version 3.2.9   i get the missing conjunction error when i use depth instead of maxdepth
`find ./ -type f -depth 1`

Comment: depth does something different, it does depth first rather than traversing each directory and then going down a level.

Answer (score 1):

`find` includes hidden dotfiles which you may not want.

This solution uses the ls command as an input array, calls ls -ld on each entry piped to grep to exclude directories with the output sent to null, and if successful echoes the original input:

```
for list in `ls` ; do ls -ld $list | grep -v ^d > /dev/null && echo $list ; done ;
```

You can invert the grep and conditional output, same results:

```
for list in `ls` ; do ls -ld $list | grep ^d > /dev/null || echo $list ; done ;
```

Comment: It's not `\dev\null`; it's `/dev/null`!